# Asp.net IIS configuration for 4.0

Tags: asp.net, iis

I created Asp.net application in 4.0 framework. I have to deploy this in test server machine. Which has installed 2.0 framework. So after configuration when i browse the page i got an error like below,

```
Line 9:    </connectionStrings>
Line 10:   <system.web>
Line 11:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
Line 12:       <assemblies>
Line 13:         <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
```

Can any one please help me in this?

Comment: How can you deploy a .net 4 application to a machine only with .net 2.0? You will not be having required assemblies.

Comment: What is the error message that you receive?

Comment: What you posted is not the error message. Kindly update you post.

Comment: My Error message as below,   Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Source Error: 


Line 9:    </connectionStrings>
Line 10:   <system.web>
Line 11:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4.0 framework needs to be installed on the test server machine. If it is, then be sure to set the App Pool for the Web Site in IIS to .net 4.0 (and .net 2.0). Then your configuration should work (2.0 expects different elements in the web.config file)

Answer (score 0):

```
Line 9:    </connectionStrings>
Line 10:   <system.web>
Line 11:     <compilation debug="true">
Line 12:       <assemblies>
Line 13:         <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
```

what happens when you remove the targetversion? Does it still work?

If you conceptualize the differences between .NET FW 1.1, 2.0. 3.5,4.0... etc... you'll notice a lot of what prevents the backwards compatibility is web.config newer code.  Otherwise, if the namespaces are all a part of that framework, it doesn't care.